# LINQ query returning null results

Tags: linq, linq-to-objects, web-scraping, nodes

I have the following code

```
nodes = data.Descendants(XName.Get("{http://schemas.microsoft.com/LiveSearch/2008/04/XML/web}Results")).Nodes();
        System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Result> res = new List<Result>();
        if (nodes.Count() > 0)
        {
            var results = from uris in nodes
                          select new Result
        {
            URL =
((XElement)uris).Element(XName.Get("{http://schemas.microsoft.com/LiveSearch/2008/04/XML/web}Url")).Value,
            Title =
((XElement)uris).Element(XName.Get("{http://schemas.microsoft.com/LiveSearch/2008/04/XML/web}Title")).Value,
            Description =
((XElement)uris).Element(XName.Get("{http://schemas.microsoft.com/LiveSearch/2008/04/XML/web}Description")).Value,
            DateTime =
((XElement)uris).Element(XName.Get("{http://schemas.microsoft.com/LiveSearch/2008/04/XML/web}DateTime")).Value,
        };
            res = results;
        }
```

Where Results is a object who has those URL, Title, Description, and DateTime variables defined.

This all works fine normally, but when a 'node' in nodes doesnt contain a Description element (or at least I think thats whats throwing it) the program hits the "res = results;"
line of code and throws a 'object reference not set to...' error and highlights the whole section right after "select new Results"..

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to cast to `string` instead of using the `Value` property. That way you'll end up with a `null` reference for the `Description` instead.

However, your code can also be made a *lot* nicer:

```
XNamespace ns = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/LiveSearch/2008/04/XML/web";

var results = data.Descendants(ns + "Results")
                  .Elements()
                  .Select(x => new Result 
                          {
                            URL = (string) x.Element(ns + "Url"),
                            Title = (string) x.Element(ns + "Title"),
                            Description = (string) x.Element(ns + "Description"),
                            DateTime = (string) x.Element(ns + "DateTime")
                          })
                  .ToList();
```

See how much simpler that is? Techiques used:

- Calling `ToList()` on an empty sequence gives you a list anyway
- This way you'll only ever perform the query once; before you were calling `Count()` which would potentially have iterated over each node. In general, use `Any()` instead of `Count() > 0)` - but this time just making the list unconditional is simpler.
- Use the `Elements()` method to get child elements, rather than casting multiple times. (Your previous code would have thrown an exception if it had encountered any non-element nodes)
- Use the implicit conversion from string to `XNamespace`
- Use the `+(XNamespace, string)` operator to get an `XName`

Comment: The problem persists.. Perhaps it wasn't a missing element from nodes. Is there a way I can write this differently to add 'safeguards'?

Comment: @Ryan: Try my alternative (simpler) code, and if that still fails, please edit a short but *complete* program (including XML) into your question so we can see what's going on.

Comment: This nicer way of writing the code avoided the problem.. thanks a lot Jon

Answer (score 1):

If the Description element is not included you should test if this

```
((XElement)uris).Element(XName.Get("{http://schemas.microsoft.com/LiveSearch/2008/04/XML/web}Description"))
```

is not null before using Value. Try this code:

```
var results = from uris in nodes let des = ((XElement)uris).Element(XName.Get("{http://schemas.microsoft.com/LiveSearch/2008/04/XML/web}Description"))
                      select new Result
    {
        URL = ((XElement)uris).Element(XName.Get("{http://schemas.microsoft.com/LiveSearch/2008/04/XML/web}Url")).Value,
        Title = ((XElement)uris).Element(XName.Get("{http://schemas.microsoft.com/LiveSearch/2008/04/XML/web}Title")).Value,
        Description = (des != null) ? des.Value : string.Empty,
        DateTime = ((XElement)uris).Element(XName.Get("{http://schemas.microsoft.com/LiveSearch/2008/04/XML/web}DateTime")).Value,
    };
```